# Get actual WiFi credentials in Xamarin Forms

Tags: forms, xamarin, get, wifi, credentials

I wish to get actual wifi credetials (username and password), if the smartphone is already connected in wifi to the router.

I need to write this credentians to an external card (via bluetooth) and I wish don't ask the actual credentials to the user.

Thanks.

Comment: that sounds like a horrible security hole

Comment: Horrible? So much? Practically the security of android / ios does not allow to know these data?

Comment: You just cannot by (operating system security) design.